# Find UMVUE for p when the pdf is $f(x; p) = p(1-p)^{x - 1}$

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

Let $x \in \mathbb{N}$, and let the pdf of the random variable $X$ be $f(x; \theta)  = p(1-p)^{x - 1}$. I want to find the UMVUE for $p$.

It can be shown that $f$ is in the regular exponential class and thus $S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient and complete statistic for $p$. Thus, if I can find an unbiased estimator for $p$ involving $S$, that statistic with be a UMVUE for $p$.

Unfortunately, $E[S] = \frac{n}{p}$ Thus, $E\left[\bar X\right] = \frac{1}{p}$, and it is a UMVUE for $\frac{1}{p}$, but it does *not* follow that $\frac{1}{\bar X}$ is a UMVUE for $p$.

So then how can I get a UMVUE for $p$ from $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a common technique. First find any unbiased estimator for $p$. In this case, it's easy to see that,

$$ T(\textbf{X}) = \begin{cases}1 & X_1 = 1\\
0 & otherwise \end{cases} $$

is unbiased for $p$. By conditioning on the complete sufficient statistic, $\mathbb{E}[T(\textbf{X}) | S]$ is unbiased and must be the UMVUE by Lehmann-Scheffe. Try to find a closed form for $\mathbb{E}[T(\textbf{X}) | S]$. To get you started,

$$ \mathbb{E}[T(\textbf{X}) | S = s] = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1 | \sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i = s) $$

Comment: So I'm guessing that somehow I need to turn $S$ into $T(\mathbf{X})$. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: That edit seems to be more helpful. I heard that the sum is a negative binomial random variable, so it's possible to get a closed form for some probabilities that appear when expanding out the conditional probability. After some work, I think I found that $\mathbb{E}[T(\mathbf{X}) | S] = \frac{n - 1}{S - 1}$. Is this correct?

Comment: That seems correct to me!